# ¿Como puedo saber cuanto tiempo tengo mi cursor sobre un div en js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eh estado buscando como saber el tiempo en milisegundos o segundos que pasa el cursor sobre un div, esto quiere decir que si pongo mi cursor sobre un div quisiera obtener el tiempo que se queda mi cursor ahí para después procesar esa información.
Actualmente no tengo ningún código que me pueda servir para eso

Comment: puedes detectar el evento de entrada y salida a la división con hover de jquery. Cuando el cursor ingresa solo tienes que contar tiempo y cuando el cursor sale para la cuenta. Espero que te sirva para empezar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo utilizando jQuery, primero se detecta el evento en que el cursor entra en el `div` y se guarda la fecha y hora en que sucedió, y otro evento para cuando el cursor salga del `div`, se vuelve a guardar la fecha y hora, y con ambas se calcula la cantidad de segundo que duro el cursor dentro del `div` y se muestra el resultado.

```js
var dateStart;
var dateEnd;

$('.zone').on('mouseenter', function() {
  dateStart = new Date();
  dateEnd = null;
  $('.info').html('');
});


$('.zone').on('mouseleave', function() {  
  dateEnd = new Date();
  var duration = (dateEnd - dateStart) / 1000;
  $('.info').html(duration + ' segundos');
});
```

```css
.zone {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.info {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 25px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zone"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```